# Has pandas.stats been deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate RSI using the following formula and I am getting the following error. Has pandas.stats been depreciated?

```py
    def RSIfun(series, period=14):
        series = series['Close']
        delta = series.diff().dropna()
        delta = series.diff().dropna()
        u = delta * 0
        d = u.copy()
        u[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
        d[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
        u[u.index[period-1]] = np.mean( u[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg gains
        u = u.drop(u.index[:(period-1)])
        d[d.index[period-1]] = np.mean( d[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg losses
        d = d.drop(d.index[:(period-1)])
        rs = pd.stats.moments.ewma(u, com=period-1, adjust=False) /     pd.stats.moments.ewma(d, com=period-1, adjust=False)
        return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
```

**Error**

```
Error: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'stats'
```

Comment: see this PR: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11603, explaining the new API with some example  translations from the older one.

Comment: Yes, it depreciated 50% in value.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Its surprising to me. My program ran just 2 days ago, but the pull request seems to be from 2015. I changed the last line to rs = u.ewm(com = period-1,adjust = False).mean()/d.ewm(com = period-1,adjust = False).mean()

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Marigold/universal-portfolios/issues/20) may be worth checking.

Comment: A whole new approach for pandas dealing with rolling calculations seems to be in an instance method for a dataframe called `rolling`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html