# module 'pandas' has no attribute 'stats' Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble with pandas for some reason. No problems when I import it, nor read the .txt file into a dataframe. But it doesn't recognize .stats as its attribute. Below are the code and the message error:

```py
import time, sys, json 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

def RSI(series, period):
    delta = series.diff().dropna()
    u = delta * 0
    d = u.copy()
    u[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
    d[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
    u[u.index[period-1]] = np.mean( u[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg gains
    u = u.drop(u.index[:(period-1)])
    d[d.index[period-1]] = np.mean( d[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg losses
    d = d.drop(d.index[:(period-1)])
    rs = pd.stats.moments.ewma(u, com=period-1, adjust=False)
    pd.stats.moments.ewma(d, com=period-1, adjust=False)
    return 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
```

And now the message error:

`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'stats'`

Comment: Related: [Has pandas.stats been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57055894/2745495)

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) seems like your best bet

Comment: It works! Thanks Trenton! Thanks everyone!